# Count of distinct ID in dataset SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is sample query:

What I want is count of distinct id for each RWL to be populated against each record.

I want to do it in one query as my actual data set is very big.

```
create table temp_ayush
(id int,
RWL varchar(10),
cost int)

insert into temp_ayush
values
(1,'ABC',100),
(1,'ABC',200),
(2,'XYZ',300),
(2,'ABC',100)

select * 
,count(id) over (partition by RWL)
from temp_ayush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than partitioning by `RWL`, use a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT DISTINCT` instead, like so:

```
select RWL
,count(distinct id) 
from temp_ayush
group by RWL
```

Note that because this uses `GROUP BY` you can only select columns included in the group by clause.

If you require the other columns, I'd suggest using the above in a join, like so:

```
SELECT  RWL,
        IdCount,
        Cost
FROM    temp_ayush
JOIN    (    select RWL
            ,count(distinct id) 
            from temp_ayush
            group by RWL
        )   T
ON      T.RWL = RWL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp_ayush
(id int,
RWL varchar(10),
cost int)

insert into #temp_ayush
values
(1,'ABC',100),
(1,'ABC',200),
(2,'XYZ',300),
(2,'ABC',100)

select t.* 
,c.Cnt
from #temp_ayush t
    JOIN (
        SELECT RWL, COUNT (DISTINCT ID) AS Cnt
        FROM #temp_ayush
        GROUP BY RWL
    ) c ON c.RWL = t.RWL

drop table #temp_ayush
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these queries:

1) If you want imitation of window function (`count(distinct ..)` can't be used as window function), use:

```
select id,
       RWL,
       (select count(distinct ID) from temp_ayush where RWL = ta.RWL) countDistinct,
       cost
from temp_ayush ta
```

2) if you want grouping, use:

```
select RWL, count(distinct ID) from temp_ayush
group by RWL
```

Comment: Well i seriously think count distinct with partition should have been implemented by MSFT when windows function was introduced.. i will  use group by followed by join to retain my entire columns...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
select  *, (select count(distinct id) from #temp_ayush b where a.rwl = b.rwl)
from    #temp_ayush a
```